# TypeVar annotating arguments versus returns

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Considering a case where there's a parent class and several children inherited from that parent. Set up a `TypeVar` for type hinting the child when the child being passed or returned. For simplicity and illustartion, only one child was created.

```
from typing import TypeVar


class Parent(object):
    pass

class Child(Parent):
    pass

T_co = TypeVar("T_co", bound=Parent)
```

`mypy` would response differently depending on where the type hinting being applied. When applies to return, `mypy` would raise the following error

```
def hint_return() -> T_co:
    return Child()
```

```
Incompatible return value type (got "Child", expected "T_co")mypy(error)
```

But no complaints were raised by `mypy` when applies to argument.

```
def hint_arg(child: T_co):
    pass

register_arg(Child())
```

Why this discrepancy appears? And what are the correct ways to use `TypeVar` for type hinting for returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two implicit rules for how you must use TypeVars:

1. A TypeVar must be used at least once in your argument type hints.
2. A TypeVar must appear at least twice within a function's signature.

If you don't follow these two rules, you either end up constructing a function type signature that doesn't really do much and contains a superfluous TypeVar or is impossible to perform type inference on.

Your `hint_return` function is an example of a function that breaks rule 1. The reason why this is problematic is because when mypy sees a call like:

```
x = hint_return()
```

...it attempts to infer what the type of `x` is using *just* the information available in the call site and in the type signature -- it does not examine the body of `hint_return`.

(But what if mypy tried using the pre-existing type of `x` as a hint? Well, there's no possible way `hint_return` could actually take advantage of that information at runtime, so that information therefore cannot possibly be relevant for type inference purposes. This is again a reflection of rule 1: a TypeVar is meant to be replaced with a more specific type when the function is called, which means you need to actually specify what that specific type *is* as input.)

Your `hint_arg` function is an example a function that violates rule 2. In this case, your TypeVar ends up serving no purpose: it'd be simpler to just rewrite your function as:

```
def hint_arg_simplified(child: Parent):
    pass
```

After all, replacing T_co with the actual type that's passed in serves no purpose. Since `hint_arg` still needs to be capable of accepting any arbitrary subtype of Parent, they way you'd implement `hint_arg` and `hint_arg_simplified` are going to have to be exactly the same, no matter what.

(Remember that if a function is typed to accept a Parent, it must actually accept Parent and any subtype of Parent. That is mypy assumes your types follows the Liskov substitution principle and performs type checking accordingly)

But doing:

```
T = TypeVar('T', bound=Parent)

def two_args_v1(x: T, y: T) -> None: pass
```

...is very different from doing:

```
def two_args_v2(x: Parent, y: Parent) -> None: pass
```

In the former, we know x and y must be the exact same type while we didn't know that for the latter. This is relevant and new information that could be used during type inference.

---

One note of clarification regarding generic classes. On the surface, it may seem like they violate these rules. For example, the mypy is perfectly happy with the following class definition even though it seems like it violates both rules! Why?

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    # Violates rule 2?
    def __init__(self, x: T) -> None:
        self.x = x

    # Violates rule 1 and 2?
    def unwrap(self) -> T:
        return self.x
```

Well, it's because we're actually not looking at the complete type signature. We normally omit the type from `self`, but they're actually all still there. Once we add back in the automatically inferred `self` type, it becomes clear both rules are actually being followed after all:

```
class Wrapper(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self: Wrapper[T], x: T) -> None:
        self.x = x

    def unwrap(self: Wrapper[T]) -> T:
        return self.x
```